# my custom backend and model not saving int column

Tags: magento-1.9, model

here is the code in my controller of my custom backend, the save action

```
public function saveAction () 
{

    $id = $this->getRequest()->getPost('id');


    if ($id) {

        $action = $this->getRequest()->getPost('action');
        $details = $this->getRequest()->getPost('details');

        $model = Mage::getModel('modulename/modulename');
        $model->setData('action', $action);
        $model->setData('customer_id', $id);            
        $model->setData('details', $details);

        $model->save();

    } else {
        Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addError('No id'); 
    }


}
```

when i click the button to save the form data, the customer_id won't save to db (0 in db, other column is ok), anyone know what is the problem?

Comment: where do you get the `$id` from? It looks to me like it is not initialized.

Comment: @marius updated

Comment: are you sure you are getting ID in POST ?

Comment: var_dump($this->getRequest()->getParam('id')); try this and check

Comment: are you sure the id is numerical? If it's a string it will pass the `if` condition but when you converted to int it will turn to 0.

Comment: echo $id; die(); will print out the id

Comment: if you have just created new columns to table , flush cache

Comment: also make sure that the column is named `customer_id`. Check for typos.

Comment: @hkguile welcome. note this for future reference